# Selenium (Python) Click at position of a previously located element

Tags: python, selenium, element, locate

I'm very new to Selenium (2 days in). I'm trying to write a script that will help me book a delivery slot from a local supermarket. The slots are updated at some random time during the day and I keep missing them no matter how often I check. 
Before the slots become available, the page shows the following

```
</span>
<div>06:00 - 08:00</div>
</div>
<div class="delivery-schedule-options">
<span class="delivery-slot-message d-xs-none d-md-inline-block">
<span class="d-md-none">Not available - more slots added soon</span>
<span class="d-xs-none d-md-inline">Not available - more slots added soon</span>
</span>
```

I'm wanting to identify the location of the 'Not available - more slots added soon' text and click on it when the page updates with available slots. 
The page scroll may change so I don't want to take the position relative to some corner of the browser window. Maybe identifying the element to the right of the time range (06:00 - 08:00) is possible?

Until slots become available, I don't know exactly what the xml shows in order for me to identify the element directly, and I've not seen them become available since I started looking in to solving this problem with Selenium.

Yes, some may find this approach morally objectionable. But I am including my elderly neighbor's requirements in my order, if that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
elements=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='delivery-schedule-options']//span[contains(text(),'Not available')]");
```

Comment: May I ask, will this give me a clickable item, even if the page refreshes to replace the Not Available text? For example, if I were to put in a while loop and check that Not Available exists, then when the page refreshes so that Not available' is replaced with something else (yet unknown), will  
{
elements.click()
}
still execute the desired click on the location that has replace Not Available?

Comment: No @Miakatt , this line of code `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='delivery-schedule-options']//span[contains(text(),'Not available')]")` allows you to identify a span with text includes 'Not available' phrase, if text changed, the element wont be identifiable/clickable. Let me ask you, are aiming to identify the available slots? Or you need to capture those 'not available' slots and then track them until become available ? (if you can, plz share the targeted url)